# More concise way of checking if a character is equal to a set of given characters in Python?

Tags: python

is there a cleaner way I can write this function? Some kind of thing in Python like a function in the standard library, or a fancy syntactical feature?

```
def is_separator(char):
    x = ['(', '\'', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']']
    for c in x:
        if char == c:
            return True
    return False
```

I considered using a dictionary, but I imagine theres a better way? I tried doing `char in "(\){}[]"` but that just returns false. So far the above is my best attempt.

Comment: "I tried doing `char in "(\){}[]"` but that just returns false." - maybe because you forgot the `'`? And why is that considered a separator, anyway?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I'm moving from mainly C/Rust to Python, so I'm not too familiar with it's idioms. And in the context, it's a visual separator.

Comment: because `\)` is not a valid escape sequence

Comment: trivially `return char in "()'{}[]"` (thanks to python ability to use single and double quotes, escaping those is rare.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get rid of the `for` loop and do:

```
return char in x
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Store your x as a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). So `{'(', '\'', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']'}` . This way, you get O(1) and not O(n).
2. `if char in x` works for sets as well

So

```
sep = {'(', '\'', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']'}
       #initializing on the outside so it's not created
       #every time the function is called. 
       #initializing a set is O(n). Indexing into it is O(1)
def is_sep(char, sep):
    return char in sep
```

Comment: or `set(r"(\){}[]")` if you feel daring :P +1 for the good suggestion of a set ... although I doubt he will notice much performace gain with only 7 characters

Comment: the size of the sequence is constant. searching through all elements of a constant-sized list is o(1)

Comment: @JoranBeasley It's for a lexer, so this would be a frequent operation; so this answer does help me a lot :)

Comment: @njzk2 do you have a source for that ... Im pretty sure using a list is `O(N)` ... dicts and sets are `O(1)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: N is the size of the list where the list has a dynamic size. Here, the size is 7, so `O(1)`.

Comment: @metro-man: if it's a frequent operation, you may want to define the set outside of your function as well. As is, the way in my answer would re-initialize the set every time it's run.

Comment: Im pretty sure you are partially right in that it is `O(7)` which is roughly `O(1)` ... however set and dict lookups are truly O(1) since they are looked up in a hash table instead of walking through the list

Comment: @JoranBeasley But that's no fun! I wouldn't have run into this problem if I used regex :)

Comment: But you'd run into all the fun regex problems!

Comment: (As an aside ... writing a lexer/grammar (or even compiler) is a good learning experience ... however there is a whole lot of headache to get a mediocre language at best (usually)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Don't worry about that, it's not a serious project and I've written my fair share of compilers/interpreters :)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use a list

and also it is considered an antipattern to do something like

```
def check():
    if condition:
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

since you can just do

```
def check():
    return condition
```

all that said ... I think you might be looking for

```
is_sep = lambda char:char in r"(\){}[]"
```

might be what you are looking for ... I guess

```
def is_sep(char):
    return char in r"(\){}[]"
```

if your set of characters is large you may be better off using a `set` ... if you are searching a lot of text you may be better served with something like

```
parts = re.split(r"[(\){}[]]",my_complete_text)
```

Comment: For the anti-pattern stuff, if I did return c == char, then it would just return false or true depending on the item in the array on the first iteration

Comment: sort of except your esentially doing `any(char == c for c in x)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest way :

```
def is_separator(char):

    x = ['(', '\'', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']']

    return char in x
```